# No property found for type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr

When running my code to fetch data from Solr, it fails to compile with exception:
`Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findSubscriptions found for type Subscriptions!`

I don't see inconsistency in naming or missing method. 
Code is for fetching the data from Solr. I have already created a document and Solr is UP and running on "http://localhost:8983/solr/"

1)

```java
      @RestController
      public class SubscriptionsController {

      @Autowired
      SolrSubscriptionsRepository solrSubscriptionsRepository; 

      @GetMapping("/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}")
      public Subscriptions getSubscriptions(@PathVariable Long subscriptionId) {

        solrSubscriptionsRepository.findSubscriptions(subscriptionId);
        return solrSubscriptionsRepository.findSubscriptions(subscriptionId);


      }
```

2)

```java
     @SolrDocument(collection= "Subscriptions")
     public class Subscriptions {

     @Id
     @Indexed(name="subscription_id", type="long")
     private Long subscriptionId;

     @Indexed(name="subscription_query", type="string")
     private String subscriptionQuery;

     @Indexed(name="subscription_type", type="string")
     private String subscriptionType;

     }
```

3)

```java
     public interface SolrSubscriptionsRepository extends 
     SolrCrudRepository<Subscriptions, Long>{

     Subscriptions findSubscriptions(Long subscriptionId);

     }
```

4)

```java
      @Configuration
      @EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages="com.test.repository")
      @ComponentScan
      public class SolrConfig {

      @Value("spring.data.solr.host") String solrURL;

      @Bean
      public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrURL).build();
      }

      @Bean
      public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient solrClient) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient);
        }
      }
```

5)
       *application.properties*
    `spring.data.solr.host=http://localhost:8983/solr/`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Comment: I want to delete my question, itself, how do I do that

Comment: User should have an option to edit the question, like here just want to remove the specific piece of codes but not deviate from the original question and answer. OR I can put a different question with all the edited details and put the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution1

```java
@Autowired
  SolrSubscriptionsRepository solrSubscriptionsRepository; 

  @GetMapping("/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}")
  public Subscriptions getSubscriptions(@PathVariable Long subscriptionId) {

    solrSubscriptionsRepository.findSubscriptions(subscriptionId);
    return solrSubscriptionsRepository.findById(subscriptionId);
  }
```

Solution 2:

```java
@Autowired
  SolrSubscriptionsRepository solrSubscriptionsRepository; 

  @GetMapping("/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}")
  public Subscriptions getSubscriptions(@PathVariable Long subscriptionId) {

    solrSubscriptionsRepository.findSubscriptions(subscriptionId);
    return solrSubscriptionsRepository.findBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
  }
```

```java
public interface SolrSubscriptionsRepository extends SolrCrudRepository{
 Subscriptions findBySubscriptionId(Long subscriptionId);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you response...for solution @2 I see it the difference in method name just but seems to work, am I missing anything

Comment: @vicky
[Supported keywords inside method names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/4.1.0.M1/reference/html/#reference)

Spring data has some supported keywords for method names on the basis of these method names it execute Queries.

Comment: "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host] with root"     getting this error when calling

Comment: make sure services for solr are running.

Comment: Yes SOlr is UP and running on the same port as in application.properties. I am also able to fetch org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: IOException occured when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host] with root cause

org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified"